# How can we write Unit Test Case for the function in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, xctestcase

I want to write a unit test case for the method which is one of the delegate methods in the view controller. I created a unit test case class for the VC and am trying to write a unit test for the method.

Here is the method which is implemented in VC. **How can we write Unit Test Case?**

```
extension DownloadBaseViewController:EMPDecisionTreeCoordinatorDelegate {
    func decisionEmptyTreeFeedbackButtonTapped() {
        if let feedbackNavVc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "PremiumFeedbackNavViewController") as? PremiumCustomNavigationController {
            if let feedbackVc = feedbackNavVc.children.first as? PremiumFeedbackViewController {
                feedbackVc.id = self.fileDetails?.id
                self.decesiontreeCoordinator!.rootViewController.present(feedbackNavVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Created a unit test class for VC and tried not able to write it properly followed few tutorials not found for delegate method.

```
import XCTest


class DownloadBaseViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {
   
   var downloadBaseViewController: DownloadBaseViewController!
   
   func testDecisionEmptyTreeFeedbackButtonTapped() throws { 
       let feedbackVCNavigation = downloadBaseViewController.decisionEmptyTreeFeedbackButtonTapped
       XCTAssertNotNil(feedbackVCNavigation, "Download base view controller contains feedback view controller and succesfully able to navigate")
 
 ///Test case Build succeded but this is not the way to test it properly need heads up on this.
   }

   override func setUpWithError() throws {
       // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
   }
}
```

Comment: Your write unit test methods to verify the expected behavior, so what is the behavior you need to verify here? Also please note that to write unit tests the code must be testable, that means principally that allows the dependencies to be injected. Here if the behavior that you what to test is that when you call the method the PremiumFeedbackViewController is presented using decesiontreeCoordinator,then simply inject a Spy decesiontreeCoordinator in the controller then call the method and then check that the present method was called with the expected type of controller.

Comment: @ChristosKoninis I was not missing something to test it properly, Can you provide answer that would be helpful this time?

Comment: As I wrote previously I need to know that behavior you need to test first with the unit test method before I can provide with an more detailed example

Comment: @ChristosKoninis Updated question with my tried behaviour can you have a look and let me know.

Comment: @ChristosKoninis can you provide explanation answer awaiting for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor the `DownloadBaseViewController` in your app so you can mock the dependency:

```
extension DownloadBaseViewController:EMPDecisionTreeCoordinatorDelegate {
    // Add this variable in DownloadBaseViewController
    lazy var presentingController: ViewControllerPresenting? = self.decesiontreeCoordinator?.rootViewController

    func decisionEmptyTreeFeedbackButtonTapped() {
        if let feedbackNavVc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "PremiumFeedbackNavViewController") as? PremiumCustomNavigationController {
            if let feedbackVc = feedbackNavVc.children.first as? PremiumFeedbackViewController {
                feedbackVc.id = self.fileDetails?.id
                self.presentingController?.present(feedbackNavVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

 // You need this to mock the foreign dependency on UIViewController 
 protocol ViewControllerPresenting: AnyObject {
    func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController,
                 animated flag: Bool,
                 completion: (() -> Void)?)
}

extension UIViewController: ViewControllerPresenting {}
```

In the tests you inject a Spy object that will help you validate the correct behaviour:

```
final class UIViewControllerSpy: ViewControllerPresenting {
    var viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController!

    func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController,
                 animated flag: Bool,
                 completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.viewControllerToPresent = viewControllerToPresent
    }
}

class DownloadBaseViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

   var downloadBaseViewController: DownloadBaseViewController! = DownloadBaseViewController()

   func testDecisionEmptyTreeFeedbackButtonTapped() throws {
       // Given
       let spyController = UIViewControllerSpy()
       downloadBaseViewController.presentingController = spyController
       // When
       downloadBaseViewController.decisionEmptyTreeFeedbackButtonTapped()
       // Then
       let presentedController = spyController.viewControllerToPresent as? PremiumFeedbackViewController
       XCTAssertNotNil(presentedController, "Download base view controller contains feedback view controller and succesfully able to navigate")
   }
}
```